# wordpress disable print &nbsp on DOM

Tags: wordpress

I'm an Italian's student and i've some problems with Wordpress 4.9.6. In particular it prints some "&nbsp" on DOM, i don't understand why happens (if someone could tell me, i would be more happy)!
I've already tryed the code below:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

This doesn't work because it applies the filter in all pages of my theme and it breaks the structure created from WP editor. 
So the question is:
is there a way to apply the code above only for a specific page?

In my case the page requested is a single post page (for all single post pages).
Here an image of my DOM with inspector of Chrome about what happens:
[URL problem's link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeWjV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your content/text in "Code view" on edit page.
Seems like break lines.. (several 'Enter' pressed)